# javascript - get all anchor tags and compare them to an array

Tags: javascript

I have been trying forever but it is just not working, how can I check the array of urls I got (`document.getElementsByTagName('a').href;`) to see if any of the websites are in another array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var linkcheck = (function(){
  if(!Array.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
  for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
    if(this[i]===obj){
      return i;
    }
  }
      return -1;
    }
  }
  var url_pages = [], anchor_nodes = []; // this is where you put the resulting urls
  var anchors = document.links; // your anchor collection
  var i = anchors.length;
  while (i--){
    var a = anchors[i];
    anchor_nodes.push(a); // push the node object in case that needs to change
    url_pages.push(a.href); // push the href attribute to the array of hrefs
  }
  return {
    urlsOnPage: url_pages, 
    anchorTags: anchor_nodes, 
    checkDuplicateUrls: function(url_list){
      var duplicates = []; // instantiate a blank array
      var j = url_list.length;
      while(j--){
        var x = url_list[j];
        if (url_pages.indexOf(x) > -1){ // check the index of each item in the array.
          duplicates.push(x); // add it to the list of duplicate urls
        }
      }
      return duplicates; // return the list of duplicates.
    },
    getAnchorsForUrl: function(url){
      return anchor_nodes[url_pages.indexOf(url)];
    }
  }
})()
// to use it:
var result = linkcheck.checkDuplicateUrls(your_array_of_urls);
```

This is a fairly straight forward implementation of a pure JavaScript method for achieving what I believe the spec calls for. This also uses closures to give you access to the result set at any time, in case your list of urls changes over time and the new list needs to be checked. I also added the resulting anchor tags as an array, since we are iterating them anyway, so you can change their properties on the fly. And since it might be useful to have there is a convenience method for getting the anchor tag by passing the url (first one in the result set). Per the comments below, included snippet to create indexOf for IE8 and switched document.getElementsByTagName to document.links to get dynamic list of objects.

Comment: Note that *Array.prototype.indexOf()* isn't implemented in IE 8 and older and will require an extra snippet defining that method.  Also note that your lists are static.  You can use *document.links* to get a dynamic collection of *A* and *AREA* elements on the page.

Comment: @Andy E thanks for the info. I take for granted that the indexOf implementation is everywhere. Been using jQuery so much lately I completely spaced document.links.

Answer (score 21):

*getElementByTagName* gives you a nodelist (an array of nodes).

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var idx= 0; idx < a.length; ++idx){
    console.log(a[idx].href);
}
```

I really suggest that you use a frame work for this, like jquery. It makes your life so much easier.

Example with jquery:

```
$("a").each(function(){
  console.log(this.href);
});
```

Comment: That's pretty straightforward, though - would it really be easier with jQuery? I think it might actually take MORE characters to be all '$().attr('blahblah'), etc.

Comment: @Mark: I added an example with jquery. As you see it's less to type.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery u can do some thing like this-

```
$('a').each(function(){
if( urls.indexOf(this.href) !- -1 )
    alert('match found - ' + this.href );
})
```

urls is the your existing array you need to compare with.